# Under what conditions the following constraint is convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

We know that if a matrix $\mathbb{A}$ is positive definite then $tr~\mathbb{A}$ is a convex function. But how can we show that the following constraint results in a convex set $$-tr~\mathbb{AQ}\leq 0$$ where $\mathbb{Q}$ is some matrix with constant real values.

Comment: @supinf thus far I only know how to show that $tr ~\mathbb{A}$ is a convex function (this is an exercise in Stephen Boyd book). But I do not know how to show that by multiplying $\mathbb{A}$ by $\mathbb{Q}$ it becomes a concave function.

Comment: Have you tried to write out a formula for $-\mbox{tr} AQ$ in terms of the elements of $A$ and $Q$?

Comment: @BrianBorchers ok now I know that its a linear function so it is both convex and concave at the same time

Comment: So, you know that $-\mbox{tr}(AQ) $ is a convex function and your constraint is of the form convex function of A is less than 0.  Is that enough to establish that the feasible region is convex?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I think so. Here is the reason why I think so (please correct me if I am wrong). As the function on the left side is convex therefore its sublevel set is convex for any level. Since this is also true for level=0, I conclude that the constraint result in a convex set. (Please let me know if this reasoning is wrong. Thanks in advance.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Brian Borchers hinted at, it is a composition of two linear operations (multiply with a constant matrix, and trace), so the whole thing $Tr(AQ)$ is linear in $A$ given $Q$.

If you want to show it the long way, assume there are $A_1,A_2$ that satisfy the constraint, i.e. $-Tr(A_1 Q) \leq 0$,$-Tr(A_2 Q) \leq 0$. For any $\theta \in [0,1]$, let $A_3 = \theta A_1 + (1-\theta) A_2$ be the convex combination of the two matrices, then we have

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
-Tr(A_3 Q) &= - Tr ((\theta A_1 + (1-\theta)A_2) Q) \\
&= -Tr(\theta A_1Q + (1-\theta) A_2 Q) \\
&= - \theta \cdot Tr(A_1Q) - (1-\theta) \cdot Tr(A_2Q) \\
&\leq 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where the last equality comes from the linear nature of trace operator and the inequality is from the simple fact that sum of two $\leq 0$ entities is still $\leq 0$. Therefore $A_3$ is still in the same set for arbitrary $\theta \in [0,1]$, hence the feasible set is convex.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you please also answer/comment on this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091183/help-needed-in-understanding-the-following-lemma